# How can I add space in between my Tabs in my TabPane?

Tags: java, css, tabs, javafx

I am trying to add a gap between my Tabs in my TabPane using CSS. I have tried a number of things, but it never seems to be what I want. I tried Insets and they gave me the space, but they also had a darker color. If I could make the Insets transparent, but keep the space, that would be fine. I also tried padding, but I couldn't get it to give me any space. I am trying to create a 5 pixel gap. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks.

EDIT:

```css
.Tab {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(35,31,32);
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-border-color:-default-border-color;
    -fx-border-width:1;
    -fx-padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Above I tried padding, but it did not work.

```css
.Tab .tab-label {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: -title-text-fill-color;    
}

.Tab:selected .tab-label {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: -default-highlight;          
}

.tab-content-area {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width:1;
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent -default-border-color transparent;
}


.Tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-width:1;
    -fx-border-color: -default-border-color -default-border-color transparent -default-border-color;
}
```

Comment: Hi, hard to help without seeing your code. Can you create a jsfiddle showing what you have?

Comment: My code isn't in javascript. I'm using java. I can give you some CSS code that I have, but I'm not sure that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-fx-padding`, you can use `-fx-border-width:5px;` it also looks like padding and works fine.